# Xcode simulator: Persistent store migration failed, missing mapping model

Tags: xcode

I am working on my first iOS application and started to implement Core Data.  When I run the app on the simulator I get:

> Persistent store migration failed, missing mapping model.
>
> Can't find mapping model for migration.

When I search this I find information about migration and mapping models, but I am not working with a migration and TBH I don't even know what a mapping model is.  I have been able to use core data when I have done online Xcode dev lessons and could browse to the DB and open it.

I tried running the app on my iPhone, works perfectly.  A bit more difficult to download the sandbox and review when I am only in the initial states of development.  The only think I can think of is OSX and XCode both updated recently.

Any advice on how to get the app running on my simulator?

Comment: It looks like you made a change to CoreData models after having installed the application on the simulator. Try deleting the app from the simulator.

Comment: Thank you!  I ended up transitioning to Realm and got a similar error and was able to google the same solution.  I presume that would have worked with Core Data as you suggested.  Appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Just realised the error happens in the Xcode *simulator*, not the previewer. In that case, you just have to delete the app from the simulator `Long press app icon -> Delete app`, go back to Xcode and re-run it. If it still doesn't work, you can do a complete wipeout of the simulator by going to `Device -> Erase all Content and Settings`. I will also leave the old answer for those who struggle with this error in the previewer.

**Old answer:**
This happens when you make changes to your CoreData model. It expects you to map the old model to the new model. But since you're working in the previewer you don't care about data loss. So, there are caches you can clear in order to get around that, you can find detailed guides in other threads.

**However,** there's a trick I've found that spares you a lot of headaches:

1. Clean your build folder `Product -> Clean Build Folder`
2. Just switch the previewer to a different device, like in the pic bellow

[image]

Note: Xcode Version 14.3.1; deployment target: iOS 16.4